# Catching up with 'require' for a metamodel class

Tags: raku

I have defined own metamodel class to create a special kind of classes. Now, I would like these classes to automatically register themselves with a special kind of manager. Basically, this would like like this (would only `compose` be called each time when class' module is being loaded):

```
use MyManager;

class MyHOW is Metamodel::ClassHOW {
    method compose ( Mu \type ) {
        self.add_parent( type, MyParentClass );
        callsame;
        registerMyClass( type );
    }
}
```

Then I have something like:

```
use v6;
use MyClass;
myclass Foo { ... }
```

in a module. Then there is a manager object which scans repositories/file system and `require`s modules with names matching to a certain pattern. Afterwards, it needs to know what `myclass`es are defined in each module. It could scan the symbol table of the loaded module. But this won't work if the loaded file contains multiple modules or no modules at all – like in the example above.

So far, it looks like the `INIT` phaser would provide the solution, but I'm struggling to find how to get the body block of a class from within the `composer` method.

Comment: Once you "require" a module, you can [access its symbols using the FQN](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules#index-entry-require). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Is that `myclass` supposed to be `my class`? If so, I don't have anything for you. If not, it sounds like https://github.com/jnthn/oo-actors might be helpful.

Comment: @jjmerelo, FQN would be great but it is not guaranteed that in a file loaded with `::('My::Foo::Module')` there will be module named `My::Foo::Module`; or it is the only module in that file. I can apply extra restriction for the future developers using my module but would be happy to provide more freedom.

Comment: @raiph `myclass` is a keyword declared same way, as in `OO::Actors`.

I have edited my sample code to include the key part of the question – the registration line. That's the line I need to call whenever a `myclass` gets imported. With the sample code it would executed only once, at the precompilation stage. I need it to be called same moment, when `INIT` phaser is executed.

Comment: In a desperate attempt to get the desired behavior I'm playing with $*W inside the `compose` method. Line `$*W.context.cur_code_object().add_phaser('POST', { note "AUTOGEN" } );` inside the method results in `Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Null; VMNull)` error. Though I'm not even sure `cur_code_object` returns class' block here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing meta-programming, the meta-object's methods are invoked during compilation, as declarations are parsed. Therefore, the `compose` method is called immediately after the parsing of a `myclass foo { }` declaration. The result of the module's compilation is then saved, and nothing in the meta-object will be processed again when the module is loaded.

There's no supported way that I'm aware of to inject a load-time callback into the module where a type is being declared. However, it's possible to install the symbols into a separate package - used as a registry - and then find them there.

For example, given I have a `lib/MyClass.pm6` that looks like this:

```
package MyRegistry { }

class MyParentClass { }

class MyHOW is Metamodel::ClassHOW {
    method compose ( Mu \type ) {
        MyRegistry::{self.name(type)} = type;
        self.add_parent( type, MyParentClass );
        callsame;
    }
}

my package EXPORTHOW {
    package DECLARE {
        constant myclass = MyHOW;
    }
}
```

And I write some files `mods/A.pm6` and `mods/B.pm6` like this:

```
use MyClass;
myclass A { }
```

And this:

```
use MyClass;
myclass B { }
```

Then when I require them in a script like this, and dump the keys in `MyRegistry`, they'll both be registered there:

```
use MyClass;
for dir('mods', test => /pm6$/) {
    require $_;
}
dd MyRegistry.WHO.values;
```

Thus giving a predictable way to find them all.

Note that for a technique like this to work, you really need to have them stored into a `Stash`, since the loader knows how to symbol-merge those, whereas other types touched in different ways during the compilation of different modules will result in load-time conflicts.

You are left with the slight challenge of making sure to install everything under a sufficiently unique key; the type name as I used here is probably not unique enough in general. Probably I'd just generate something sufficiently random that the chance of a collision is hugely unlikely.

Comment: That's brilliant! I was thinking about storing the types somewhere, but didn't consider a stash for that purpose. Neither I knew it is stored in precompiled data. Thank you! _PS._ Just out of curiousity: is it still possible to inject own phaser into a class block?

Comment: In terms of official API, I don't seen an obvious way to do that. Roles do receive the body block, but at the moment the compiler hard-codes the package declarator name `role` to do that. Even if it didn't, there's a timing problem: that block is finalized (and has its phasers code generated) before the `set_body_block` call, so that'd be too late too. In "hack" territory, however, there's `$*CODE_OBJECT` in the dynamic scope when `new_type` is called, and you could call `add_phaser` on that. Of course, then you're at the mercy of compiler internals changes.